# Styling a background image of a plotline in a highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

```
     plotLines: [{
                    value: 1.2873,
                    color: 'green',
                    label: {        
                        style: {
                             color:'red'
                             background-color:'#000',
                             background-image:'url(image.jpg)',
                        },
                    }
                }],
```

Is this how it should be? Also, is it possible to style a value of plotLine with an image (for example, a gif) from an external file?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately background images are not supported, but you can request your proposition here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com